# Is there a way to use TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE as a Function input in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to create an Oracle SQL Function which accepts a TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE value as an input parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func ( timetz IN TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE ) // Not going to work 
   // code here
   BEGIN 
      // code here
   END;
```

And then try to pass inputs as below. I am trying to set a different timezone provided by the user as a `ZonedDateTime` value. In the below code, current `LocalDateTime` is taken as an example.

```
public void myFunc( )
{
    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{call my_func ( ? )}");  
    stmt.setObject( ZonedDateTime.of( LocalDateTime.now() ), java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE);  
    stmt.execute(); 
}
```

What would be the ideal way to do this.

Comment: The JDBC specification only defines support for `java.time.OffsetDateTime` for `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do that. In case, anyone needs help with this question, I will post the work around I used.

1. Pass the date with timezone as a VARCHAR2 to the Function

   CREATE FUNCTION my_func ( timetz IN VARCHAR2 )
   // code here
   BEGIN
   // usage
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( timetz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR')
   END;
2. Pass the Timestamp with timezone as a String from java

   SimepleDateFormatter sdf = new SimpleDateFormatter('yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss')
   sdf.format( new Timestamp() ) + " " + "Pacific/US"

   stmt.setString( 1, timestampTZString );